# Model not accepted by view (ViewDataDictionary) and/or view expecting different model than it supposed to, why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I have .net core web app based on razor pages. I use a _Layout structure with some partials and pages that need to be rendered in @renderbody(). I have a _Sidebar partial with links that should link to the pages that should load in the @renderbody() section. I add the link using the asp-page directive and I scaffold a razor page item (view + pagemodel) in the Pages folder. I do not make any changes to the scaffolded code in the files. I only add the name of the files to the asp-page directive in the sidebar link. I run the web app and click the link and I get the following error:

`InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'NN.NetworkManagementPortal.Pages.WhitelistingModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'DeliveryPlanner.Pages.IndexModel'.`

Where is the problem? I am doing the exact same process as in a different project where I have no problem whatsoever.

Sidebar:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-page="Index">
                        <i class="ni ni-settings text-blue"></i> Configuration Items List
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-page="Whitelisting">
                        <i class="ni ni-pin-3 text-orange"></i> White-list IP
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-page="About">
                        <i class="ni ni-single-02 text-yellow"></i> About  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial">
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Whitelisting View:

```
@page
@model NN.NetworkManagementPortal.Pages.WhitelistingModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Whitelisting";
}

<h2>Whitelisting</h2>
```

Whitelisting PageModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace NN.NetworkManagementPortal.Pages
{
    public class WhitelistingModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link, your request goes throw your controller to get the model and its data. Then, it tries to bind this model to the view.

You did not provide the code of the controller but it seams the controller's action is returning the wrong model type.

You constrained your view to use a model of type **@model NN.NetworkManagementPortal.Pages.WhitelistingModel**, 
but your controller is trying to give a model of type **DeliveryPlanner.Pages.IndexModel** to the view.

Double check your controller's action, the problem should be solved by returning a **WhitelistingModel** rather than an **IndexModel**.

Comment: But this is Razor, there is no controller... I believe this is handled by the ```asp-page``` directive and I cannot control that, can I. Regarding the difference in the namespace, I fixed that but it had no influence on it.

Comment: Yeah it's true, it is not MVC, even if it is based on MVC. My bad. However, could it be because you return void in your WhitelistingModel rather than the model itself ?

Comment: I believe it cannot. That does not make any sense to me. It should just show nothing in case of the empty OnGet but since the Index works, I tried to copy the razor page and view for it and just rename it (including the constructor etc.), so the OnGet is not void anymore and actually contains working code, it still resulted in the same error message. There is something in the background forcing it to the index but I have no idea what and where since in my other projects it works fine as described in my steps.

Comment: Sadly I do not have other idea. I did not paid enough attention on the fact your were talking about Razor Pages. I have faced the same kind of issue with mixed razor-MVC in the past, and I thought I could help you. Sorry and, good luck. :)